# Faster Way to Update Duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

My goal is to update one column of the duplicates, but only the second+ ( the first should be kept unchanged ), for example:

df_example:

```
    Name    val1     val2     val3   
0   AAA     11        3        1
1   AAA     22        3        1
2   BBB     33        2        2
3   CCC     44        3        3
4   DDD     55        2        4
5   DDD     66        2        4
6   DDD     77        3        4
```

The expected Output would be :

```
    Name  val1   val2     val3   
0   AAA    11    3        1
1   AAA    22    3        0
2   BBB    33    2        2
3   CCC    44    3        3
4   DDD    55    2        4
5   DDD    66    2        0
6   DDD    77    3        4  ( unchanged because Val2 is different )
```

I am currently using iterrows ( I know it's the worst option, but I couldn't find a better option ):

```
list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    if (row['Name']+row['val2'] in list):            # Check for Name + Val2
        row['val3'] = '0'                             
    list.append(row['Name']+row['val2'])    # Inserts the new Name+Val2 in the list , next time 
                                                 #this combination appears will fall in the if statement
```

For not so small data sets ( ~ 1MM rows ) this takes around 20 min... It's too much

Thanks,

Comment: so basically, if there is a duplicate you want to change column `val3` to 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df[['Name', 'val2']].duplicated()` to create a series of `bool`s that determine if the combination was already present. We can then use that mask to set the value for the val3` column:

```
df.loc[df[['Name', 'val2']].duplicated(), 'val3'] = 0
```

For the given sample data, this gives us:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'DDD', 'DDD'], 'val1': [11,22,33,44,55,66,77], 'val2': [3,3,2,3,2,2,3], 'val3': [1,1,2,3,4,4,4]})
>>> df
  Name  val1  val2  val3
0  AAA    11     3     1
1  AAA    22     3     1
2  BBB    33     2     2
3  CCC    44     3     3
4  DDD    55     2     4
5  DDD    66     2     4
6  DDD    77     3     4
>>> df.loc[df[['Name', 'val2']].duplicated(), 'val3'] = 0
>>> df
  Name  val1  val2  val3
0  AAA    11     3     1
1  AAA    22     3     0
2  BBB    33     2     2
3  CCC    44     3     3
4  DDD    55     2     4
5  DDD    66     2     0
6  DDD    77     3     4
```

If we repeat the number of records in the sample dataframe 200'000 times, and we run the above, hundred times, we obtain the following benchmark:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'DDD', 'DDD']*200000, 'val1': [11,22,33,44,55,66,77]*200000, 'val2': [3,3,2,3,2,2,3]*200000, 'val3': [1,1,2,3,4,4,4]*200000})
>>> def f():
...     df.loc[df[['Name', 'val2']].duplicated(), 'val3'] = 0
... 
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(f, number=100)
11.420697326015215
```

For a dataframe with 1.4M rows, we thus can do the processing on average in 0.1142 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Similair to Willem's answer : we can use a bool to return the indices of and then apply an assignment via a `.loc` method.

```
indices = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['Name','val2'],keep='first')].index
# assign these as 0
df.loc[indices, 'val3'] = 0
print(df)
```

and the result :

```
    Name    val1    val2    val3
0   AAA 11  3   1
1   AAA 22  3   0
2   BBB 33  2   2
3   CCC 44  3   3
4   DDD 55  2   4
5   DDD 66  2   0
6   DDD 77  3   4
```

Comment: Just be careful with this if the Index is not unique.

Comment: @ALollz you are right, should I remove this answer?